# Sql Filesystem programming Python

Tags: python, sql, database, image

Hi Everyone Ive hit a road block in sql. Its the dreaded storing images in sql database. Apparently the solution to this is to store image in a file system.  Does anyone know any book or video tutorial that teaches this I cant seem to find any in the web. Im using My Sql and Python to learn how to work with images. I cant find any examples in the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the image as a file, and store the path of the file in the database.

The fact that the file is an image is irrelevant. If you want a more specific answer, you will need to ask a more specific question. Also, please edit your title so that it corresponds to the question.